# iframe source physical file or object

Tags: html, iframe

Hi I want to pass an object as iframe src. Is it possible?

like this

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

myiframe.Attributes.Add("src", s);
```

Thank you,
Nagu

Comment: what are you trying to pass - a link value or the content. what is your goal for using an iframe?

Comment: actually i want to pass one url to iframe and select specific text after that save it into my local database

Comment: And you can't use an AJAX based solution for this? Iframes are a bit old-hat and clunky!

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't set any value other then a url to iframe's source (src) attribute.

But if the text you want to set contains html content you can add it into a placeholder instead.

**EDIT :** I think you're using ASP.NET, and assume that you have a placeholder in your asp.net page like that :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phContent"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

you can set your content at code behind inside this placeholder like that :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

phContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(htmlContent));
```

Comment: can you give me a simple example